# perlbrew list-modules fails to show module for an aliased perl install

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I have 2 versions of perl-5.18.1 installed.

One was built with the alias perlt (threaded), the other built as perl-5.18.1 then 'aliased' to perlp (plain, not threaded). When using perlt the perlbrew list-modules works as expected, but when using perlp no results are shown even though both installs have the same set of modules.

In the Perls directory are 3 files:

- perl-5.18.1
- perlt
- perlp which is a link to the perl-5.18.1 file.

Is there a simple way to correct this? When I use perl-5.18.1 the command perlbrew list-modules gives the expected result.

Obviously, I could use this as a work-around, but I am wondering if there are other situations where this 'odd behaviour' might cause problems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same thing when I try it here. It's a bug with list-modules, confirmed here:
https://github.com/gugod/App-perlbrew/issues/336

Answer (score 0):

In a subsequent installation, I used the -as option during the installation step eg.

perlbrew install 5.18.1 (other stuff omitted...) -as perlpand find that

perlbrew list-modules

seems to work just fine. My original problem appeared only after 'aliasing' an already installed Perl.